# send file over socket in javascript

Tags: javascript, sockets, xmpp, openfire

i want to send file using [socks5 ByteStream](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0065.html) in javascript , i know how to handle file request negotiation using [si-file transfer](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0096.html) but once the nagotiation finishes , i dont know how i am gonna send raw file using ip address and port in javascript.

i have seen may libraries in C++ , java , Python but i don't know how to send raw file over socket in javascript.

please do suggest some way to implement it so that  i can send file over socket in javascript itself

i am using openfire server for xmpp